# How do I use reflection to invoke a method with parameters?

Tags: java, reflection, dynamic, types, parameters

Here is my class:

```
public class A{
    private void doIt(int[] X, int[] Y){
       //change the values in X and Y
    }
}
```

I have another class that is trying to use `doIt` to modify two arrays. I have an error in my code but can't find it.

```
public class B{
  public void myStuff(){
    A myA = new A();
    int[] X = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int[] Y = {4,5,6,7,8,9};
    Method doIt = A.class.getDeclaredMethod("doIt",new Object[]{X,Y}); // error
    doIt.setAccessible(true);
    doIt.invoke(myA,new Object[]{X,Y});
  }
}
```

Any help on how to fix method `myStuff`?

If I use `getDeclaredMethod("doIt",new Object[]{X,Y});` the code does not compile.

If instead I have `getDeclaredMethod("doIt",null);` then it says `NoSuchMethodException`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your method is declared with two int arrays

```
private void doIt(int[] X, int[] Y)
```

and if you wan to find that method you also need to put its argument types to prevent finding other method with same name but different types.

```
A.class.getDeclaredMethod("doIt", int[].class, int[].class)
```

Answer (score 5):

The `doIt` method takes **two** parameters. Consequently you need to pass **two** parameters, in addition to the method name, to [`Class#getDeclaredMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29). The two additional parameters need to be instances of [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html), which an `Object[]` is obviously *not.* Specifically, those `Class` instances need to be the same as the types of the parameters that `doIt` accepts.

```
Method doIt = A.class.getDeclaredMethod("doIt", int[].class, int[].class);
```

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't it be?

```
Method doIt = A.class.getDeclaredMethod("doIt", int[].class, int[].class);
```